# C++03: Add fields to several derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, derived-class

I have several derived classes (e.g. `DerivedX`, where x is derived class number) that differ in fields and member functions.
Than I want to extend each derived class with some set of properties (can be organised as a field `Extension ex`), preserving each `DerivedX` class. The latter means, that we could create "clear" `DerivedX` objects that would not contain the property `Extension ex`.

The derived objects are created in some code place (e.g., in function `main()`), than, if they possess an extended functionality, this functionality should be used (get,set, other methods are called from `main()`).

The first idea was to add this new property to every derived class forming new class (`ExtendedX`) for each of derived classes. But I feel the code would become bulky, it seems, this approach is bad:

```
class Base
{
protected:
int b;
...
}

class Derived1: public Base
{
protected:
int d1;
...
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
protected:
int d2;
...
}
...X classes defined

class Extended1: public Derived1
{
protected:
Extension ex;
public:
int getExProperty1(){return ex.getProperty1();} // the realization could differ: we could also return copy of Extension object, pointer, set every field separately or the whole Extension object
}

class Extended2: public Derived2
{
protected:
Extension ex;
public:
int getExProperty1(){return ex.getProperty1();} // the realization could differ: we could also return copy of Extension object, pointer, set every field separately or the whole Extension object
}
...X classes defined
```

The demanded functionality is repeated in each class in that case. It's highly deprecated practice.

The other (second) idea was to declare "class Extension" that would contain the property considered (`"Extension ex"` in the example) and create its objects on-demand along with the objects of classes `DerivedX`, when we need `DerivedX` objects to possess this property.

The third idea was to include pointer to `Extension` as a field to the Base class and simply initialize it to NULL when we don't want to use the extended functionality. But then, how can we call methods of `Extension` class from `main()`?

Extended functionality could also be different in the future (derived classes are extended in accordance with the kind of problem being solved), that's why the second and the third ideas are also better, than the first.

Is there any good solution to add pack of properties and functionality to multiple derived classes?

---

EDIT1:
I tried to implement mixin through CRTP, as suggested by Deduplicator.
However, the code fails with:

```
«class Base» has no member named «getProperty1»
«class Base» has no member named «setProperty1»
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
   int a;
public:
   virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
   virtual ~Derived1(){}
};

template <class T> class Extension: public T
{
   int prop1;
 public:
   void setProperty1(int _p){prop1=_p;}
   int getProperty1(){return prop1;}
};

int main()
{
Base* der = new Derived1();
Base* e = new Extension<Derived1>();
e->setProperty1(10);
cout<< e->getProperty1();
delete der;
delete e;
return 0;
}
```

Changing

```
e->
```

to

```
static_cast<Extension<Derived1> *>(e)->
```

makes the code working.

How to use `Extension` class objects right in this case?

Comment: What you're looking for is the concept of class trait or mixin. The simplest way is to define a class containing the parts common to all `Derived*` classes, and have each of them inherit it (like you do for `Base`). The caveat is that this new ancestor can only work with whatever would be common to all derived classes, ie what is in `Base` and of course what it brings by itself

Comment: It's quite confusing to talk about `Derived<x>` when you mean `Derived1`, `Derived2` etc. because `Derived<x>` looks like a template. It would be less confusing to say `DerivedX`

Comment: Technically, you should use `dynamic_cast<Extension<Derived1> *>(e)` and check that this cast does not return `nullptr`, e.g. write `if(Extension<Derived1> *ed1 = dynamic_cast<Extension<Derived1> *>(e)) { /* use ed1-> here. */ } else { /* e is not an Extension<Derived1> */ }`.

Comment: Jonathan Wakely: about `DerivedX` - fixed this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CRTP:

```
// Classes implementing additions

template<class T> class Extended : public T /*, potentially additional bases */ {
    // Common extension here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you can redefine the various `Derived` classes but can't change the definition of `Base`, is to shove `Extension` into the class hierarchy between them and `Base`:

```
class Base
{ // ...
};

class Extension: public Base
{ // ...
};

class Derived1: public Extension
{ // ...
};

class Derived2: public Extension
{ // ...
};
```

This way, anything that doesn't need the new APIs in `Extension` can continue to use `Base*`, and the parts that need the new API can use `Extension*` (or `dynamic_cast<Extension>(baseptr)`) instead.

This assumes `Extension` needs access to `Base`. If it doesn't, then you can just implement `Extension` as a mixin:

```
class Base
{ // ...
};

class Extension
{ // ...
};

class Derived1: public Base, Extension
{ // ...
};

class Derived2: public Base, Extension
{ // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Composition or inheritance ?**

> when we need Derived objects to possess this property.

This sounds as if an object and its extended property have a "**has-a**" and not and "**is-a**" relationship.  This would suggest composition rather than inheritance as solution.

> "on demand" , "if we don't want" ...

These suggest an optional relationship.  It sounds as if you'd decide at runtime and for each object if the extension is needed or not.  This reinforces the preference for composition over inheritance.

To achieve this kind of behaviour with inheritance needs polymorphism, and you'd have to use pointers/references everytime you need to work with an object.

> Extended functionality could also be different in the future (derived
>   classes are extended in accordance with the kind of problem being
>   solved),

In the future, could there be further derivation for the derived ? If yes, how would this further derivation relate to the extension ?  If you'd say that further derivation would be independent of the extension, then composition should definitively be the choice.

**Now which one of 2 and 3 to prefer ?**

Looking at all the arguments above,  the third option could be very interesting for both your current needs for a common extension, but also future needs.

Here is the general idea:

```
class Base {
   ...
protected:
   Extension *ex;
   void setExtension(Extension *e);   // to be called by ctor or the derived.
public:
   bool isExtended() { return ex!=nullptr; } 
   int getExProperty1(){ if (isExtend()) return ex->getProperty1();} // common member functions 
};
```

But for this to remain extensible for future evolutions, `Extension` should define its member functions virtual.  Then later some derived class could use a derivation of Extension:

```
class MyDerivedExtension : public Extension {  // specially for Derived1 extensions
protected:
    string myspecificproperty;   // specific for Derived1
public:  
    int getPropery1 () { /* calculate it differently than for basic Extension */ }
    string getProperty2 () { /*...*/ }  // specific to Derived1
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
...
protected:  
   void setExtension(MyDerivedExtension *e) { Base::setExtension(e); }  // to be called by ctor.     
public: 
   string getExProperty2(){ if (isExtend()) return ex->getProperty2();} // non common member         
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. However, for every property of Extended class we should write wrapping getter/setter in the Base class (or Derived, if it is non-common property). Using template + inheritance, as suggested by Deduplicator, seems more convinient way to create on-demand extension (mixin, as didierc told) for arbitrary class.

Comment: "for every property of Extended class we should write wrapping getter/setter in the Base class" -- *only* if the API represented by those properties should be accessible to every user of `Base`. Also, if this is the case, it is an indication that the original API of `Base` was incomplete, and is a good argument to refactor that part of `Base`.